# How to share memory across multiprocessors in python?

Tags: python, syntax, multiprocessing

I have a very big dictionary and I would like to process it by multiprocessing as follow:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
with mp.Pool() as p:
    # x is a dictionary of dictionary, f is a function, v is a dictionary
    y = dict(p.map(f, ((k, v, *something*) for k, v in x.items())))
```

However, the above is even slower than single processing. I suspect that copying my large dictionary to each subprocessor makes it slow. I try *manager* but I did not find a correct syntax. I would like to ask for the correct way to share memory across multiprocessor in python.

Since I will reuse the subprocessor many time, it would be also good to preload the dictionary in each subprocessor. But again, I did not find the right syntax.

Comment: In your case the operating system is quite important. There are systems that support fork and handle that data efficiently, there can even be a copy-on-write fork where data is only copied when modified, and of cause there is Windows which doesn't support both and everything has to be serialized expensively.

Comment: Try using function `imap` instead of `map` and specify a *chunksize* parameter (a good value would be approximately the number of keys on `x` divided by (4 * pool size). So if you had 8 cores and 100_000 entries in `x`, you would use a *chunksize* value of 100_000 // 32. This should at least be of some help.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. The problem of slow speed is to copy the whole data (~5GB) to each subprocessor. I believe a way to solve it is to treat the separate logical cores of the CPU as different servers.  Each server preload different parts of the data and receive request from the main server. However, does python support this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeed to preload my dataset using *mp.Process*.

The code is as follow:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class mySubprocess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, path, in_queue, out_queue, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.my_dict = ** preload something **
        self.in_queue = in_queue
        self.out_queue = out_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            my_input= self.in_queue.get()
            my_return = ** do something **
            self.out_queue.put(my_return)

class myClass:
    def __init__(self, path_list, *args, **kwargs):
        n = len(path_list)
        self.in_queue = [mp.Queue()] * n
        self.out_queue = [mp.Queue()] * n
        self.processes = [mySubprocess(path, self.in_queue[i], self.out_queue[i]) for (i, path) in enumerate(path_list)]
        for p in self.processes:
            p.start()

    def run(self, ** something **):
       for q in self.in_queue:
            my_input = ** do something **
            q.put(my_input)
        
        output_list = []
        for q in self.out_queue:
            my_return = q.get()
            output_list.append(my_return)
```